# Implement Django admin TabularInline form in template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I want to implement forms like admin TabularInline forms in Django template. (I think we're gonna need `inlineformset_factory` for this kind of forms and jquery for dynamic add remove buttons.)

this is my model:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile-update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"


class FamilyMember(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    relationship = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I will appreciate as well if you just guide me find a way out to the solution in comments.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Cause you've shown no effort to solve your problem and normally people use this kind of language to describe a freelance job.

Comment: cause i don't know where should i start and i think it's fine to ask this kind of question. i asked to see if there is experienced developer who have gone this journey to help with this

Comment: there is alot of questions like this that answered well by community

Comment: Personally, I felt the tone you have used here is more like an employer/client, not a help-seeking developer/colleague.

Comment: sorry for that. maybe it's for my bad English. I'm not a native English person

Comment: what do you suggest sir?

Comment: Please clarify your issue. It's not clear to me what's not working at the moment. Are you trying to make your admin panel work, or you want to use admin's inline templates in your custom templates?

Comment: yes sir. second one. i want inline forms in my templates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally figured out how to do it. here is the full working sample code: (appname is myprofile)

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone


class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile-update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"


class FamilyMember(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    relationship = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, inlineformset_factory

from .models import FamilyMember, Profile


class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        exclude = ()


class FamilyMemberForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FamilyMember
        exclude = ()


FamilyMemberFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Profile, FamilyMember, form=FamilyMemberForm, extra=1)
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.db import transaction
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView, DeleteView, ListView, UpdateView

from .forms import FamilyMemberFormSet
from .models import Profile


class ProfileList(ListView):
    model = Profile


class ProfileCreate(CreateView):
    model = Profile
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']


class ProfileFamilyMemberCreate(CreateView):
    model = Profile
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile-list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(ProfileFamilyMemberCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['familymembers'] = FamilyMemberFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['familymembers'] = FamilyMemberFormSet()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        familymembers = context['familymembers']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if familymembers.is_valid():
                familymembers.instance = self.object
                familymembers.save()
        return super(ProfileFamilyMemberCreate, self).form_valid(form)


class ProfileUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    success_url = '/'
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']


class ProfileFamilyMemberUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile-list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(ProfileFamilyMemberUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['familymembers'] = FamilyMemberFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        else:
            data['familymembers'] = FamilyMemberFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        familymembers = context['familymembers']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if familymembers.is_valid():
                familymembers.instance = self.object
                familymembers.save()
        return super(ProfileFamilyMemberUpdate, self).form_valid(form)


class ProfileDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Profile
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile-list')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ProfileList.as_view(), name='profile-list'),
    path('profiles/add/', views.ProfileFamilyMemberCreate.as_view(), name='profile-add'),
    path('profiles/<int:pk>', views.ProfileFamilyMemberUpdate.as_view(), name='profile-update'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>', views.ProfileDelete.as_view(), name='profile-delete'),
]
```

and i have following templates in root of:

```
---templates
-----myprofile
-------profile_confirm_delete.html
-------profile_form.html
-------profile_list.html
-----base.html
```

**base.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}My amazing site{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext'  type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content" class="container">
    <div class="md-col-10">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**profile_confirm_delete.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h2></h2>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ object }}"?</p>
            <input type="submit" value="Confirm"/>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**profile_form.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Profile</h2>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}

            <table class="table">
                {{ familymembers.management_form }}

                {% for form in familymembers.forms %}
                    {% if forloop.first %}
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    {% endif %}
                    <tr class="{% cycle row1 row2 %} formset_row">
                        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                            <td>
                                {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                                {% if forloop.first %}
                                    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                        {{ hidden }}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                {% endif %}
                                {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                                {{ field }}
                            </td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Save"/> <a href="{% url 'profile-list' %}">back to the list</a>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'formset/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.formset_row').formset({
            addText: 'add family member',
            deleteText: 'remove',
            prefix: 'familymember_set'
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

**profile_list.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

    <h2>Here are all user profiles: </h2>
    <div>
        <ul>
            {% for profile in object_list %}
                <li>{{ profile.first_name }} {{ profile.last_name }} | <a
                        href="{% url 'profile-update' profile.pk %}">edit</a>
                    <a href="{% url 'profile-delete' profile.pk %}">delete</a>
                </li>
            {% empty %}
                <li>No profile yet.</li>
            {% endfor %}

        </ul>
        <p>
            <a href="{% url 'profile-add' %}">add a profile</a>
        </p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

and here is **javascript** in path of 'base_path/static/formset/jquery.formset.js'

```
;(function($) {
    $.fn.formset = function(opts)
    {
        var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.formset.defaults, opts),
            flatExtraClasses = options.extraClasses.join(' '),
            totalForms = $('#id_' + options.prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS'),
            maxForms = $('#id_' + options.prefix + '-MAX_NUM_FORMS'),
            minForms = $('#id_' + options.prefix + '-MIN_NUM_FORMS'),
            childElementSelector = 'input,select,textarea,label,div',
            $$ = $(this),

            applyExtraClasses = function(row, ndx) {
                if (options.extraClasses) {
                    row.removeClass(flatExtraClasses);
                    row.addClass(options.extraClasses[ndx % options.extraClasses.length]);
                }
            },

            updateElementIndex = function(elem, prefix, ndx) {
                var idRegex = new RegExp(prefix + '-(\\d+|__prefix__)-'),
                    replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx + '-';
                if (elem.attr("for")) elem.attr("for", elem.attr("for").replace(idRegex, replacement));
                if (elem.attr('id')) elem.attr('id', elem.attr('id').replace(idRegex, replacement));
                if (elem.attr('name')) elem.attr('name', elem.attr('name').replace(idRegex, replacement));
            },

            hasChildElements = function(row) {
                return row.find(childElementSelector).length > 0;
            },

            showAddButton = function() {
                return maxForms.length == 0 ||   // For Django versions pre 1.2
                    (maxForms.val() == '' || (maxForms.val() - totalForms.val() > 0));
            },

            /**
            * Indicates whether delete link(s) can be displayed - when total forms > min forms
            */
            showDeleteLinks = function() {
                return minForms.length == 0 ||   // For Django versions pre 1.7
                    (minForms.val() == '' || (totalForms.val() - minForms.val() > 0));
            },

            insertDeleteLink = function(row) {
                var delCssSelector = $.trim(options.deleteCssClass).replace(/\s+/g, '.'),
                    addCssSelector = $.trim(options.addCssClass).replace(/\s+/g, '.');
                if (row.is('TR')) {
                    // If the forms are laid out in table rows, insert
                    // the remove button into the last table cell:
                    row.children(':last').append('<a class="' + options.deleteCssClass +'" href="javascript:void(0)">' + options.deleteText + '</a>');
                } else if (row.is('UL') || row.is('OL')) {
                    // If they're laid out as an ordered/unordered list,
                    // insert an <li> after the last list item:
                    row.append('<li><a class="' + options.deleteCssClass + '" href="javascript:void(0)">' + options.deleteText +'</a></li>');
                } else {
                    // Otherwise, just insert the remove button as the
                    // last child element of the form's container:
                    row.append('<a class="' + options.deleteCssClass + '" href="javascript:void(0)">' + options.deleteText +'</a>');
                }
                // Check if we're under the minimum number of forms - not to display delete link at rendering
                if (!showDeleteLinks()){
                    row.find('a.' + delCssSelector).hide();
                }

                row.find('a.' + delCssSelector).click(function() {
                    var row = $(this).parents('.' + options.formCssClass),
                        del = row.find('input:hidden[id $= "-DELETE"]'),
                        buttonRow = row.siblings("a." + addCssSelector + ', .' + options.formCssClass + '-add'),
                        forms;
                    if (del.length) {
                        // We're dealing with an inline formset.
                        // Rather than remove this form from the DOM, we'll mark it as deleted
                        // and hide it, then let Django handle the deleting:
                        del.val('on');
                        row.hide();
                        forms = $('.' + options.formCssClass).not(':hidden');
                    } else {
                        row.remove();
                        // Update the TOTAL_FORMS count:
                        forms = $('.' + options.formCssClass).not('.formset-custom-template');
                        totalForms.val(forms.length);
                    }
                    for (var i=0, formCount=forms.length; i<formCount; i++) {
                        // Apply `extraClasses` to form rows so they're nicely alternating:
                        applyExtraClasses(forms.eq(i), i);
                        if (!del.length) {
                            // Also update names and IDs for all child controls (if this isn't
                            // a delete-able inline formset) so they remain in sequence:
                            forms.eq(i).find(childElementSelector).each(function() {
                                updateElementIndex($(this), options.prefix, i);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    // Check if we've reached the minimum number of forms - hide all delete link(s)
                    if (!showDeleteLinks()){
                        $('a.' + delCssSelector).each(function(){$(this).hide();});
                    }
                    // Check if we need to show the add button:
                    if (buttonRow.is(':hidden') && showAddButton()) buttonRow.show();
                    // If a post-delete callback was provided, call it with the deleted form:
                    if (options.removed) options.removed(row);
                    return false;
                });
            };

        $$.each(function(i) {
            var row = $(this),
                del = row.find('input:checkbox[id $= "-DELETE"]');
            if (del.length) {
                // If you specify "can_delete = True" when creating an inline formset,
                // Django adds a checkbox to each form in the formset.
                // Replace the default checkbox with a hidden field:
                if (del.is(':checked')) {
                    // If an inline formset containing deleted forms fails validation, make sure
                    // we keep the forms hidden (thanks for the bug report and suggested fix Mike)
                    del.before('<input type="hidden" name="' + del.attr('name') +'" id="' + del.attr('id') +'" value="on" />');
                    row.hide();
                } else {
                    del.before('<input type="hidden" name="' + del.attr('name') +'" id="' + del.attr('id') +'" />');
                }
                // Hide any labels associated with the DELETE checkbox:
                $('label[for="' + del.attr('id') + '"]').hide();
                del.remove();
            }
            if (hasChildElements(row)) {
                row.addClass(options.formCssClass);
                if (row.is(':visible')) {
                    insertDeleteLink(row);
                    applyExtraClasses(row, i);
                }
            }
        });

        if ($$.length) {
            var hideAddButton = !showAddButton(),
                addButton, template;
            if (options.formTemplate) {
                // If a form template was specified, we'll clone it to generate new form instances:
                template = (options.formTemplate instanceof $) ? options.formTemplate : $(options.formTemplate);
                template.removeAttr('id').addClass(options.formCssClass + ' formset-custom-template');
                template.find(childElementSelector).each(function() {
                    updateElementIndex($(this), options.prefix, '__prefix__');
                });
                insertDeleteLink(template);
            } else {
                // Otherwise, use the last form in the formset; this works much better if you've got
                // extra (>= 1) forms (thnaks to justhamade for pointing this out):
                template = $('.' + options.formCssClass + ':last').clone(true).removeAttr('id');
                template.find('input:hidden[id $= "-DELETE"]').remove();
                // Clear all cloned fields, except those the user wants to keep (thanks to brunogola for the suggestion):
                template.find(childElementSelector).not(options.keepFieldValues).each(function() {
                    var elem = $(this);
                    // If this is a checkbox or radiobutton, uncheck it.
                    // This fixes Issue 1, reported by Wilson.Andrew.J:
                    if (elem.is('input:checkbox') || elem.is('input:radio')) {
                        elem.attr('checked', false);
                    } else {
                        elem.val('');
                    }
                });
            }
            // FIXME: Perhaps using $.data would be a better idea?
            options.formTemplate = template;

            if ($$.is('TR')) {
                // If forms are laid out as table rows, insert the
                // "add" button in a new table row:
                var numCols = $$.eq(0).children().length,   // This is a bit of an assumption :|
                    buttonRow = $('<tr><td colspan="' + numCols + '"><a class="' + options.addCssClass + '" href="javascript:void(0)">' + options.addText + '</a></tr>')
                                .addClass(options.formCssClass + '-add');
                $$.parent().append(buttonRow);
                if (hideAddButton) buttonRow.hide();
                addButton = buttonRow.find('a');
            } else {
                // Otherwise, insert it immediately after the last form:
                $$.filter(':last').after('<a class="' + options.addCssClass + '" href="javascript:void(0)">' + options.addText + '</a>');
                addButton = $$.filter(':last').next();
                if (hideAddButton) addButton.hide();
            }
            addButton.click(function() {
                var formCount = parseInt(totalForms.val()),
                    row = options.formTemplate.clone(true).removeClass('formset-custom-template'),
                    buttonRow = $($(this).parents('tr.' + options.formCssClass + '-add').get(0) || this)
                    delCssSelector = $.trim(options.deleteCssClass).replace(/\s+/g, '.');
                applyExtraClasses(row, formCount);
                row.insertBefore(buttonRow).show();
                row.find(childElementSelector).each(function() {
                    updateElementIndex($(this), options.prefix, formCount);
                });
                totalForms.val(formCount + 1);
                // Check if we're above the minimum allowed number of forms -> show all delete link(s)
                if (showDeleteLinks()){
                    $('a.' + delCssSelector).each(function(){$(this).show();});
                }
                // Check if we've exceeded the maximum allowed number of forms:
                if (!showAddButton()) buttonRow.hide();
                // If a post-add callback was supplied, call it with the added form:
                if (options.added) options.added(row);
                return false;
            });
        }

        return $$;
    };

    /* Setup plugin defaults */
    $.fn.formset.defaults = {
        prefix: 'form',                  // The form prefix for your django formset
        formTemplate: null,              // The jQuery selection cloned to generate new form instances
        addText: 'add another',          // Text for the add link
        deleteText: 'remove',            // Text for the delete link
        addCssClass: 'add-row',          // CSS class applied to the add link
        deleteCssClass: 'delete-row',    // CSS class applied to the delete link
        formCssClass: 'dynamic-form',    // CSS class applied to each form in a formset
        extraClasses: [],                // Additional CSS classes, which will be applied to each form in turn
        keepFieldValues: '',             // jQuery selector for fields whose values should be kept when the form is cloned
        added: null,                     // Function called each time a new form is added
        removed: null                    // Function called each time a form is deleted
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer really saved the struggle I have been having. It is really great.

Answer (score 4):

imagine we have two models, model_A and model_B as follows:

```
class model_A(models.Model):
    # some fields it has

class model_B(models.Model):
    fk_field = models.ForeignKey(
      model_A,
      verbose_name=_("model A obj"),
      related_name='fk_reverse', 
      # this related_name is used as formsets prefix. so rember this to see where its used
      on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    # some fields for model B
```

## forms.py

```
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory

TestFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
  model_A,
  model_B,
  form=ModleBForm,
  exclude=('some fields', ),
  extra=1,
  can_delete=False
)
```

## step 1: create a template for formset like this bellow:

## formset.html

```
{% load static %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset.forms %}
  <table id="duration" class="table table-striped table-inline table-responsive">
      {% if forloop.first %}
          <thead>
          <tr>
              {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                  <th> {{ field.label }} </th>
              {% endfor %}
          </tr>
          </thead>
      {% endif %}
      <tbody>
          <tr class="formset_row">
              {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                  <td>
                      {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                      {% if forloop.first %}
                          {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                              {{ hidden }}
                          {% endfor %}
                      {% endif %}
                      {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                      {{ field }}
                  </td>
              {% endfor %}
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
{{ form.media }}
{% endfor %}
```

## step 2: the template that will contain the formset

## from.html

```
<form id="form_with_formset" action="#" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <table class="table">
    {{ form.as_table }}
  </table>

  <!-- this inputs value indicates the we want to add or remove a row -->
  <input id="wtd" name="wtd" type="hidden" value="1">

  <div id="formset_container">
      {% include 'formset.html' %}
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-target-url="{{ request.path }}" id="addNewRow">add new row</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-target-url="{{ request.path }}" id="remLastRow" disabled="disabled">delete last row</button>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">submit</button>
</form>
```

#step 3: use the power of Javascript!.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

      // formset control
      $('#addNewRow').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          var ajax_link = this.getAttribute('data-target-url');

          // +1 to indicate this a request to add new formset instance
          $('#form_with_formset').find('#wtd').val(1);

          $.ajax({
              url: ajax_link,
              data: $('#form_with_formset').serialize(),
              type: 'POST',

              success: function(res) {
                  // clear the formset container and then fill it with the-
                  // response of ajax call. the response contains the-
                  // previous formset instance plus one new instance 
                  $('#formset_container').empty();
                  $('#formset_container').append(res);
              }
          });

          $('#remLastRow').removeAttr('disabled');
      });

      $('#remLastRow').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          var ajax_link = this.getAttribute('data-target-url');

          // at least one formset instance is mandatory
          if ($('#formset_container').children('table').length > 1) {

              // -1 to indicate this a request to remove the last formset instance
              $('#form_with_formset').find('#wtd').val(-1);

              // because I handled fromsets in separate tables so
              // for remove last instance we just remove the last child (table)
              $('#formset_container table').last().remove();

              $.ajax({
                  url: ajax_link,
                  data: $('#form_with_formset').serialize(),
                  type: 'POST',

                  success: function(res) {
                      $('#formset_container').empty();
                      $('#formset_container').append(res);
                  }
              });
          }
          // disabling remove button if just one instance remained
          if ($('#formset_container').children('table').length <= 1)
              $('#remLastRow').attr('disabled', 'true');
      });
  });

</script>
```

## step 4: urls.py

## just use your path to the form page instead of "path-to-form"

```
urlpatterns = [
  ...
  path('path-to-form', views.test_create, name="test_create"), # for function based views
  path('path-to-form', views.TestCreate.as_view(), name="test_create"), # for class based views
  ...
```

## step 5: views.py functions to handle form and formset(s)

**note function based views is not ready yet but I hope you can get something out of the class based view function here, and I'm working on the missed part to publish a.s.a.p.

```
class TestCreate(CreateView):
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      context = {
          'form': TestForm(), # form used to create model_A instance(s)
          'formset': TestFormSet(), # formset for create model_B instace(s) linked to that model_A instace
    }
    return render(request, 'form.html', context)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # if our ajax is calling so we have to take action
    # because this is not the form submition
    if request.is_ajax():
        cp = request.POST.copy() # because we couldn't change fields values directly in request.POST
        value = int(cp['wtd']) # figure out if the process is addition or deletion
        prefix = "fk_reverse" # whatever your related_name is
        cp[f'{prefix}-TOTAL_FORMS'] = int(
            cp[f'{prefix}-TOTAL_FORMS']) + value
        formset = TestFormSet(cp) # catch any data which were in the previous formsets and deliver to-
          # the new formsetes again -> if the process is addition!
        return render(request, 'formset.html', {'formset': formset})
    form = TestForm(request.POST)
    formset = TestFormSet(request.POST or None)
    theres_no_error = True # a good tip, you'll see ;)
    # important note: check any desired validation of formset here and it's helpful
    # to prevent save model_A instance if formset contains invalid data which-
    # means connected model_B instance(s) wont be created
    if formset.is_valid():
        for subform in formset:
          if subform.cleaned_data['custom_field'] is not valid_in_your_opinion: # the formset is valid but-
            # you want to check something if you'relike me crazy
            theres_no_error = False
            subform.full_clean()
            subform.errors['custom_field'] = subform.error_class(["yor message to show error"])
    if form.is_valid() and theres_no_error: # if formsets are valid too! :)
       form.save()
       for subform in formset:
          subform.save()
```